# Full screen Button Image Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I am creating an App using jQuery Mobile. I want to display a full screen Button image. As per the plan, On click, it should go to some page. I have created a button and replaced my custom image. But I am unable to stretch it to full screen.

Please help me how to go about it.

Here`s my code

CSS

```css
.button{
 width:100%;
 background-image: url('home1.png') !important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

HTML

```html
<div data-role="content" id="content" >
    <a href="#button1" class="button" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some CSS or HTML that you have tried - I think Jquery Mobile sets all of that not sure how you can over ride that. You could try something simple like width:100%; but I'm guessing you've already done that

Comment: Hi tim. Please find the code as I`ve updated the question now..

Comment: Why did you use !important ? You should avoid it. Then you could use an img or button tag instead of what you used unless you also want to add a text.

Comment: Hi FAb. Tried using the <img src> too.. Image is not covering the whole screen even if I set Width = 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
display:inline-block;
```

Test is on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMTCC/1/)

It is likely Jquery is setting the width, you could try setting the !important property although avoid this if you can, and on that note if you can try to avoid using that !important property on your background-image, it normally suggests that there is a problem further up in your CSS

Comment: What OS is it for? Is it in the emulator it's not working or is on a an actual device? Have you tried taking out the Jquery factor - so it's just a button for testing?

Comment: Android. Not working in the mobile itself. Just want to use data-transition to go for the next page. So I have to use the Button.

Comment: Just asking to remove the Jquery to see if the formatting work's - i release the function won't work :s